# Limit approaching 2a

Tags: limits, rational-functions

[image]

When I substitute 2a into x, I get 0 but the answer should be 2.. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Emily, please use latex.

Comment: Have you learned L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: You don't get 0 when you substitute 2a to x what you get is 0/0 which is not defined. Therefore L'Hopital's rule can be applied.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$x^2+ax-6a^2=(x-2a)(x+3a)$

$5x^2-10ax=5x(x-2a)$

If you can't take it from here, the answer is spoiler-protected below; mouse-over to see it.

> $$\frac{5x^2-10ax}{x^2+ax-6a^2}=\frac{5x(x-2a)}{(x-2a)(x+3a)}=\frac{5x}{(x+3a)}$$

we get,

> $$\lim_{x\to 2a}\frac{5x^2-10ax}{x^2+ax-6a^2}=\lim_{x\to 2a}\frac{5x}{(x+3a)}=\frac{10a}{5a}=2$$